# Java: Queues within A class

Tags: java, class, object, for-loop, queue

I have created a class `Book` that has a queue of another class I created, `Employees` as seen below...

```
class Employee{
String name;
int waiting_time;
int retaining_time;
int priority;

public Employee()
{
    this.waiting_time=0;
    this.retaining_time=0;
}

//getters and setters ommitted to save space

public void setPriority()
{
    priority = waiting_time - retaining_time;
}

public int getPriority()
{
    return priority;
}
}

class Book{
String name;
LocalDate start_date;
LocalDate end_date;
boolean archived;
Queue<Employee> Employees ;

public Book()
{

}

//getters and setters for end_date, start_date, archived ommitted to save space

public void setQueue(Queue<Employee> qa)
{
    Employees = qa;
}

public Queue<Employee> getQueue()
{
    return Employees;
}
```

When I attempt to add an `Employee` to the `Book's` queue...

```
public static void addEmployee(String aName, ArrayList<Book> booksToCirculate, ArrayList<Employee> employeeArray)
{
    Employee anEmployee = new Employee();
    anEmployee.setName(aName);
    employeeArray.add(anEmployee);
    for (Book b : booksToCirculate)
    {
        b.getQueue().add(anEmployee); //adds employee to each queue, where the error is at
    }

}
```

I receive a `NullPointerException` error when trying to add an Employee to the queue and I can't seem to figure out why, I've gone through my book, and it appears as if I've done it according to an example of dogs and dogtoy's they had. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong are much appreciated!

Also, if you have any questions on my code please ask, I'm rather new at classes and objects, but will do my best to explain myself!

Comment: Any chance you can include the stack trace? That usually gives a good guide to where and why the code is broken (beyond just which line).

Comment: There is no Employees queue initialization in your code. And if any of the provider answers helped your problem, accept it as answer, do not just upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize the `Queue`. You have to initialize it before accessing it, otherwise it's initialized with `null` by the compiler.

Sonce Queue is an Interface you can't do

```
    Queue<Employee> Employees = new Queue<>(); //won't work, because Queue is an interface
```

What you could do is use a `LinkedList` which implemens `Queue`:

```
    Queue<Employee> Employees = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Could I use an array for the same thing? Also, throughout my program I'll find the need to update the order of the queue, would I be able to do that through this process? And if so, how?

Comment: An array is not an implementation of Queue, so no, as long if you want to use a queue you cannot use an array. Hav a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html. There you find all classes that implment Queue. Changing the order of a LinkedList is not a problem at all.

Comment: Aww I see! So all I would have to do to add items to the `Book` queue would be... `getQueue.add(anEmployee)`?

Comment: Okay I'm starting to get it now, and to update the order of the queue I would use `getQueue`, then I'm a bit confused on how I would go about sorting it, based on priority for example. Something like `for employee in Queue, sort the queue` and then do a `setQueue.(newSortedQueue)`?

Comment: Let the Employee implement the `Comparable` interface and use `Collections.sort()`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29. You don't hav to call `setQueue()`because the sort method is sorting the passed List.

Answer (score 2):

It looks you need to create your queue. As you have not, it defaults to `null`. Hence:

```
b.getQueue()
```

is returning `null`.

So when you call

```
b.getQueue().add(...)
```

you are trying to call a method on `null` which causes the exception.

If this is the case, then the solution would be to create the queue in the `Book` constructor:

```
public Book()
{
     Employees = new Deque<Employee>(); // pick an implementation of the Queue interface
}
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot that, another question I had, is throughout my program I'll find the need to edit the order of each `Book`'s queue, will I be able to do that with my current set up? And if not, any suggestions?

Comment: Also, it says that I cannot instantiate the type Queue<Employee>, any ideas?

Comment: `Queue` is an interface, so you'll need to pick one of the [implementations,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) eg. `Deque`. I'll update the answer to use that one.

Comment: Not sure about your other question about the order. You choose a `Queue` for FIFO ordering. If you need a different order, then perhaps you shouldn't be using a `Queue`?